# Making program work on 32 bit Window OS

Tags: 32bit-64bit

I have written a program in Java on a 64 bit Window OS, but now I need my program to work on a 32 bit Window OS. How can I do this? (For making an exe file I used launch4j)

Answer (score 0):

For Java, if the machine has the Java 32-bit is installed, then running the exe alone will be enough. If you want to provide redistributable, just use the java 32-bit redistributable.

Comment: Should I use java 32-bit in my intellij idea project or I can simply point it in launch4j, where I create exe file?

Comment: I'm experienced with java, I found this link that I think is helpful to you:

https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-professional.html#prerequisites

Comment: Thanks, David, but it is too expensive))